# Can't create associated models on update action

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am having difficulty creating associated models for a has_many through relationship:

I have 3 models: **Project, Material, ProjectMaterial**

Keep in mind that the Material database table is pre-populated with 1000+ materials, and when a new projected is created, the user can then select materials they want to use for the specific construction project

I have the following schema:

```
Project < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :project_materials 
 has_many :materials, through: project_materials

Material < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :category

ProjectMaterial < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :project
 belongs_to :material
```

In the Project#Show page, I have a form for the current project, within this form, I render all the materials from the Material table, in order to be selected for the current project (fetched from the param hash).

***Upon update, I want to be able to save all selected materials into the ProjectMaterial table automatically**

Here is the form: 
[Project update form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3e2R.png)

The materials within the form are divided into categories, and rendered through a category set partial (shows the materials for a specific category) [Category partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkFEy.png)

Here is a photo of the actual app where these are shown:[Form/Partial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bIxT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use nested attributes, using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model and then on your form, create the form for the associated model using `f.fields_for`.

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through